# Does the closure make a difference with regards to an inner product?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $A:D\subset X\to X$ be a linear operator on a Hilbert space.
I am trying to understand why the following statement makes sense. Let $a,b\in X$ then, 
$$\langle a-b,c \rangle = 0 \;\; \forall c\in D(A) \implies \langle a-b,c \rangle = 0 \;\; \forall c\in \overline {D(A)}$$

---

Since the inner product is a metric, for any limit point $c$, of $D(A)$ the metric should differ only by an infinitesimally small amount, i.e. should be equal.

Is this all there is to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No infinitesimals please!

Consider that (fixing $a,b$ for now) that

$$f: X \to \Bbb C,  x \to \langle b-a, x \rangle$$
is a continuous function (even Lipschitz, as $|f(x)| \le \|b-a\|\|x\|$) and the condition $\forall x \in D(A): \langle b-a, x \rangle = 0$ just says

$$D(A) \subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$$ where the right hand side is closed
as the inverse image of a closed set, and so

$$\overline{D} \subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$$ or 
$\forall x \in \overline{D(A)}: \langle b-a, x \rangle = 0$

Or more in analysis style, use sequences: if $x \in \overline{D(A)}$ find $x_n$ in $D(A)$ such that $x_n \to x$ and then by continuity of the inner product (you probably covered that?)

$$\langle b-a, x_n \rangle \to \langle b-a,x \rangle$$

and the left hand is a constant sequence of $0$s by assumption and can only converge to $0$.

Both arguments come down to "continuity of inner product", which follows from Cauchy-Schwarz and the way we define the norm and metric etc.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.